# Error after upgrading httpx : cannot import name 'main'

Tags: pip, httpx

**Whenever I am trying to install any package using pip, I am getting this import error:**

```
> ┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~] └─$ httpx -h Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/usr/bin/httpx", line 5, in <module>
>     from httpx import main ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'httpx'
> (/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/__init__.py)
> 
> ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'httpx'
> (/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/__init__.py)
```